# IBM APPID Cannot get username in the access token?

Tags: ibm-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2, ibm-appid

I need to get username as one of the claim in the access token which i received. But in default i didn't received it. I gone through their documentation about custom claim mapping but i was still confused. Can anyone know the request body to get username as claim in access token in IBM appid?

Comment: Where do you want to get the name? Are you using Cloud Directory or any other IdP in App ID? What is returned in "sub"?

Comment: In sub i received some unique identifier.

Comment: I have an app which extracts the email / username from the ID token: https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/github-traffic-stats/blob/master/backend/ghstats.py#L319 It is using OIDC against App ID. You could try to obtain an ID token and then decode it to see its claims.